# Matplotlib colormap bug with length-4 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I have some arrays that I need to plot in a loop with a certain colormap.  However, one of my arrays is length-4, and I run into this problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

ns = range(2,8)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral')
cmap = [cm(1.*i/len(ns)) for i in range(len(ns))]
for i,n in enumerate(ns):
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=n)
    y = np.zeros(n) + i
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=cmap[i], edgecolor='none', s=50, label=n)
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Imgur]

For `n=4`, it looks like Matplotlib is applying each element of the `cmap` RGBA-tuple to each value of the array.  For the other length arrays, the behavior is expected.

Now, I actually have a much more complicated code and do not want to spend time rewriting the loop.  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've bumped into an unfortunate API design in the handling of the `c` argument.  One way to work around the problem is to make `c` an array with shape `(len(x), 4)` containing `len(x)` copies of the desired color.  E.g.

```
ns = range(2,8)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral')
cmap = [cm(1.*i/len(ns)) for i in range(len(ns))]
for i,n in enumerate(ns):
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=n)
    y = np.zeros(n) + i
    c = np.tile(cmap[i], (len(x), 1))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, edgecolor='none', s=50, label=n)
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

Another alternative is to convert the RBG values into a hex string, and pass the alpha channel of the color using the `alpha` argument.  As @ali_m pointed out in a comment, the function `matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex` makes this easy.  If you know the alpha channel of the color is always 1.0, you can remove the code that creates the `alpha` argument.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ns = range(2,8)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral')
cmap = [cm(1.*i/len(ns)) for i in range(len(ns))]
for i,n in enumerate(ns):
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=n)
    y = np.zeros(n) + i
    c = mpl.colors.rgb2hex(cmap[i])
    alpha = cmap[i][3]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, edgecolor='none', s=50, label=n, alpha=alpha)
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ooh, that's nasty! The same problem occurs when specifying an RGB color tuple for a length 3 array. Perhaps a slightly cleaner workaround would be to convert the RGB(A) tuple to a hex string using [`matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex).

Comment: @ali_m I was working on exactly that when your comment appeared.  `rgb2hex` will make it simpler--thanks!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Great, both options are great and simple...I ended up going with `rgb2hex`.  BTW, it accepts both RGB and RGBA values, so no need to supply `alpha` .

Comment: `rgb2hex` accepts RGBA values, but it ignores the alpha channel; e.g. `rgb2hex([1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5])` returns `'#ff8040'`.

Comment: Setting `alpha=` via the keyword argument still isn't perfect, since it will also affect the opacity of the marker edges. I can't really think of an easy way around this, though.